# Displaying a PDF from AWS S3 in WebView causes download instead of displaying inline

Tags: react-native, amazon-s3, webview

When I try to view a PDF from an S3 bucket in a WebView, it downloads even though the Content-Type is set to application/pdf and the Content-Disposition to inline (tried without it as well) in the AWS Management Console.

```
<WebView source={{ uri: this.tosData.link }} />
```

When getting the URL directly from S3 and pasting into Chrome, it displays as expected, without downloading. If I host the PDF on something like Google Drive, and use that link instead, it also displays as expected. Any thoughts on what could be wrong?

Comment: Did you find any solution for that? I am also not able to find.

Answer (score 0):

while uploading pdf file into s3 add 'ContentDisposition': "inline" into header, this will help you to view the content instead of downloading.

Answer (score 0):

ALL PDF viewers must in one way or another download a full web page including any referenced content such as a PDF whichever way it is embedded.

**A browser may not or does not have to display the PDF** since if it was a viral file it would be run without your permission. For that reason hardened browsers will **download the pdf and not run the content.**

You can add a flag to indicate, you say the pdf may be trusted for inline viewing, if the site page is trusted. that is why there is a setting that on handing ownership dis-position from server to client there are flags ***download or inline***

- download only
- download and optionally view inline, is preferred by the site, but does not have to be complied with.

Globally PDF viewing is controled by the PDF viewer application and the browsers security settings, such as no window.open or other pop-up.